Creating a user profile on a domain connected Windows device prior to shipping to EU
We have a number of users (300+) who work remote and are not close to the office. When they are onboarded, they have to come in, plus their password and MFA haven't been set so we can profile their device ourselves. Eventually, that device is EOL and needs to be replaced. I can't ship them a device until their user profile is loaded, and that's where my issue is.
The work around we've been using is to have them RDP into the new device while they on VPN and the device is on the network to load their profile. This is not ideal.
I would like to create a user profile from another account. I'm a domain admin and a device admin. Why can't I do this easily?
According to this 10 year old post, it isn't possible: Is it possible to preload a user profile from a domain on a workstation that will be disconnected from the DC?
Has there been any changes over the past decade on this front? My searching is not returning much helpful information.
I'd even be open to a 3rd party tool like Manage Engine that can do this. We're currently on Windows 11 with on-prem Active Directory.

Why not look into Intune? With the number of remote workers you have moving away from onprem ad would make sense. Then your users could even re-install and enroll devices themself.

Does Intune allow this? This is something we're exploring, our infra is a bit overcomplicated for reasons not worth explaining here, but Intune is on the roadmap, just uncertain when it will be deployed.

Intune can do that, yes.
